# Gaining information about a device using SD reader

Tags: linux, raspbian, sd-card, ip-address

I have a few SD cards which I forgot the static IP I assigned as well as the distribution.  I can access the card using a SD reader.  How can I gain this information?

```
bacnet@gb-f75466e7-b8e8-4706-9fe952b3d302:~ $ cat rpi.txt
─[michael@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
┌─[michael@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $cd /mnt
┌─[michael@parrot]─[/mnt]
└──╼ $ls -l
total 29152
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    14010 Nov 24  2016  bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    14273 Nov 24  2016  bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    15356 Nov 24  2016  bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    15992 Nov 24  2016  bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    17932 Nov 24  2016  bootcode.bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      302 Nov 24  2016  BUILD-DATA
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    32768 Nov 24  2016  defaults
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     2250 Nov 24  2016  INSTRUCTIONS-README.txt
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    32768 Nov 29  2016  os
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    32768 Nov 24  2016  overlays
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2653448 Nov 24  2016  recovery7.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       85 Dec 31  1979  recovery.cmdline
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   633668 Nov 24  2016  recovery.elf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        0 Nov 24  2016  RECOVERY_FILES_DO_NOT_EDIT
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2581600 Nov 24  2016  recovery.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 23683072 Nov 24  2016  recovery.rfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     9728 Nov 24  2016  riscos-boot.bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    16384 Jun  2  2017 'System Volume Information'
┌─[michael@parrot]─[/mnt]

bacnet@gb-f75466e7-b8e8-4706-9fe952b3d302:~ $
```

Comment: There are other partitions, one of which will have your `/etc` directory, you are looking for `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: @ivanivan  Ah, you mean like `/dev/sdb2`  What am I looking at on `/dev/sdb1`?  To allow SSH, I execute `sudo touch /mnt/ssh`, but not really sure how this works.

Comment: @user1032531 You're looking at the the boot partition. When the system is on it's mounted on /boot.

Comment: @user1032531 what Matt said... it is the `/boot` partition